# Do the boudanry conditions for a linear homogeneous PDE follow the superposition principle

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I am wondering if the boundary conditions for the following linear PDE can be seperated.

> $\frac{\partial F(t,x,y)}{\partial t}=\frac{\partial^2 F}{\partial x^2}+\frac{\partial^2 F}{\partial y^2}$

Suppose I have four boundary conditions in a 2D domain that

> $F(t,0,y)=1,F(t,1,y)=2,F(t,x,0)=2,\frac{\partial F}{\partial y}|_{y=1}=0$

> where $0 \leq x \leq1$ , $0 \leq =y \leq1$

Can I seperate the problem into 4 linear problems with boudanry conditions that

> $F(t,0,y)=0,F(t,1,y)=0,F(t,x,0)=0,\frac{\partial F}{\partial y}|_{y=1}=0$

> $F(t,0,y)=1,F(t,1,y)=0,F(t,x,0)=0,F(t,x,1)=0$

> $F(t,0,y)=0,F(t,1,y)=2,F(t,x,0)=0,F(t,x,1)=0$

> $F(t,0,y)=0,F(t,1,y)=0,F(t,x,0)=2,F(t,x,1)=0$

Comment: Let $F_i$ with $i = 1, 2, 3, 4$ be the solution of the PDE with the $i$-th set of boundary conditions. What PDE does $F = F_1 + F_2 + F_3 + F_4$ solve? With what boundary conditions?